# What are the upsides of generators in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, filter, generator

I know that you can use generators/list comprehensions as filters. You can do a lot with lists but what can you do with generators? Python would only make such thing as a generator if it is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest benefit of a generator is that it doesn't need to reserve memory for every element of a sequence, it *generates* each item as needed.

Because of this, a generator doesn't need to have a defined size.  It can generate an infinite sequence if needed.

Comment: @12944qwerty consider [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) which is a sequence that has no ending.  You could easily code a generator that creates each Fibonacci number in sequence until you decide to stop.

Comment: Yeah... I just tested this and it amazed me. How does python manage to store the items of a generator with no lag?

Comment: @12944qwerty it doesn't store them, that's the whole point.  It's just-in-time delivery.

Comment: Hm... makes sense. Converting a huge generator caused the program to die :/ Thank you!